# Getting the head and tail of a custom list type in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I have a custom list type:

```
data NNList a = Sing a | Append ( NNList a) ( NNList a) deriving (Eq)
data CList a = Nil | NotNil ( NNList a) deriving (Eq)
```

I'm trying to implement a function that returns the head and tail of a list:

> cListGet :: CList a -> Maybe (a, CList a)

My attempt:

```
cListGet :: CList a -> Maybe (a, CList a)
cListGet Nil             = Nothing
cListGet xs@(NotNil nxs) =
case nxs of
  Sing x        -> (x, Nil)
  Append l r    -> ((fst $ cListGet (NotNil l)), (Append (snd $ cListGet (NotNil l)), r))
```

Which to me means keep going leftwards until I get a single. Once I get the single element (head), return the element and a Nil list. This Nil list is then combined with the list before it's returned as the final result.

I'm not even sure if the logic is 100% correct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, people would normally refer to the data structure you have as a kind of tree, not as a list.  But anyway...

Problem #1: Haskell is indentation sensitive, and your `case` expression is not indented.  This leads to a parse error.

Problem #2, and the bigger one: you haven't understood how the `Maybe` type works yet.  I get the impression that you think it works like nulls in more common languages, and this is throwing you off.

In a language like, say, Java, `null` is a value that can occur where most any other value can.  If we have a method with the following signature:

```
public Foo makeAFoo(Bar someBar)
```

...then it is legal to call it either of these ways:

```
// Way #1: pass in an actual value
Bar theBar = getMeABar();
Foo result = makeAFoo(theBar);

// Way #2: pass in a null
Foo result2 = makeAFoo(null)
```

`theBar` and `null` are "parallel" in a sense, or said more precisely, *they have the same type*—you can replace one with the other in a program and it will compile in both cases.

In Haskell, on the other hand, the string `"hello"` and `Nothing` do *not* have the same type, and you cannot use one where the other goes.  Haskell distinguishes between these three things:

1. A string that's required to be there: `"hello" :: String`
2. The absence of an optional string: `Nothing :: Maybe String`
3. The presence of an optional string: `Just "hello" :: Maybe String`

The difference between #1 and #3 is what you're systematically missing in your function.  With `Maybe a`, in the cases where you do have a value you *must* use `Just`, which acts like a wrapper to signify "this isn't just an `a`, it's a `Maybe a`."

First place you're missing `Just` is the right hand sides of the `case` expressions, which we can fix like this:

```
-- This still fails to compile!
cListGet :: CList a -> Maybe (a, CList a)
cListGet Nil             = Nothing
cListGet xs@(NotNil nxs) =
    case nxs of
                       -- I added 'Just' here and in the next line:
      Sing x        -> Just (x, Nil)
      Append l r    -> Just (fst $ cListGet (NotNil l), (Append (snd $ cListGet (NotNil l)), r))
```

But this isn't the end of it, because you're doing `fst $ cListGet (NotNil l)`, which suffers from the converse problem: `cListGet` returns `Maybe (a, CList a)`, but `fst` works on `(a, b)`, not on `Maybe (a, b)`.  You need to pattern match on the result of `cListGet` to test whether it's `Nothing` or `Just (x, l')`.  (This same problem occurs also in your `snd $ cListGet (NotNil l)`.)

Third, you're using your `Append` constructor wrong.  You have it in the form of `(Append foo, bar)`, which should have no comma between `foo` and `bar`.  In Haskell this sort of thing will give you more confusing error messages than most other languages, because when Haskell sees this, it doesn't tell you "you made a syntax error"; Haskell is rather more literal than most languages, so it figures you're trying to make a pair with `Append foo` as the first element, and `bar` as the second one, so it concludes that `(Append foo, bar)` must have type `(NNList a -> NNList a, NNList a)`.

The fourth and final problem: the problem you've set yourself is not clearly stated, and thus has no good answer.  You say you want to find the "head" and "tail" of a `CList a`.  What does that mean?  In the case of the Haskell `[a]` type, with constructors `[]` and `:`, this is clear: the head is the `x` in `x:xs`, and the tail is the `xs`.

As I understand you, what you mean by "head" seems to be the leftmost element of the recursive structure.  We could get that this way:

```
cListHead :: CList a -> Maybe a
cListHead Nil = Nothing
-- No need to cram everything together into one definition; deal with
-- the NNList case in an auxiliary function, it's easier...
cListGet (NotNil nxs) = Just (nnListHead nxs)

-- Note how much easier this function is to write, because since 'NNList'
-- doesn't have a 'Nil' case, there's no need to mess around with 'Maybe'
-- here.  Basically, by splitting the problem into two functions, only
-- 'cListHead' needs to care about 'Maybe' and 'Just'.
nnListHead :: NNList a -> a
nnListHead (Sing a) = a
nnListHead (Append l _) = nnListHead l
```

So you might think that "the tail" is everything else.  Well, the problem is that "everything else" is not a *subpart* of your `CList` or `NNList`.  Take this example:

```
example :: CList Int
example = NotNil (Append (Append (Sing 1) (Sing 2)) (Sing 3))
```

The "head" is `1`.  But there is no subpart of the structure defined in `example` that contains `2` and `3` without containing `1` as well.  You'd have to construct a new `CList` with a different shape than the original to get that.  That's possible to do, but I don't see the value of it as a beginner's exercise, frankly.

In case it's not clear what I mean by a "subpart," think of the example as a tree:

```
        NotNil
          |
          v
        Append
         / \
        v   v
     Sing   Append
      |      / \
      v     v   v
      1  Sing   Sing
          |      |
          v      v
          2      3
```

Subpart = subtree.

Comment: The problem may not be clearly stated here, but it seems fairly obvious how this data structure is meant to represent a list. A non-empty list is either a single element or two non-empty lists concatenated together. In general a list is either empty or a non-empty list.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: try to rewrite this using only pattern matching and not equality-checking (`==`).

**Edit:**

First off, it's crucial that you understand what pattern matching is and how it works. I'd recommend going [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching) and reading up; there are also plenty of other resources about this on the web (Google is your friend).

Once you've done that, here's another hint: First write a function `nnListGet :: NNList a -> (a, CList a)`, then use it to implement `cListGet`.

Comment: I'm still kinda new with all this and I don't completely understand the syntax behind the data type(s). I've tried following your suggestion and I'm not really sure how to fix it. (Updated the original post)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the other (very thorough) answers: It's good to realize that your custom list is a foldable structure. This means, it represents a sequence of values that can be combined together. Such datatypes can implement [`Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html) type class. In your case, it would be:

```
import Prelude hiding (foldr)
import Data.Foldable

data NNList a = Sing a | Append (NNList a) (NNList a) deriving (Eq)
data CList a = Nil | NotNil (NNList a) deriving (Eq)

instance Foldable NNList where
    foldr f z (Sing x)          = f x z
    foldr f z (Append xs ys)    = foldr f (foldr f z ys) xs
instance Foldable CList where
    foldr _ z Nil               = z
    foldr f z (NotNil xs)       = foldr f z xs
```

From that you'll get all functions defined in `Data.Foldable` for free, such as maximum/minimum, searching for an element etc.

For any `Foldable`, you can implement `headMaybe` that returns its first element by using [`First` monoid](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Monoid.html#t%3aFirst). It's a very simple [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) that returns the left-most non-empty element. So if you fold all elements of a `Foldable` using this monoid, you'll get its first one:

```
import Data.Monoid

headMaybe :: (Foldable f) => f a -> Maybe a
headMaybe = getFirst . foldMap (First . Just)
```

(Alternatively, you can use `foldr` directly, using `Maybe`'s instance of [`Alternative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#t%3aAlternative), which again returns the left-most non-empty element:

```
import Control.Applicative

headMaybe = foldr (\x y -> pure x <|> y) Nothing
```

.)

However, this doesn't solve the second part of your question - computing `tailMaybe`. This can't be defined in a generic way like `headMaybe`, and you'll need your custom function for that, as you did.

See also:

- [Fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) on Wikipedia.
- [Foldable and Traversable](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldable_and_Traversable) on Haskell wiki.
- [Fold](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold) on Haskell wiki.
- [List processing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/List_processing) on Haskell wikibook.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you declare that in terms of two types? Here's a seemingly more appropriate type declaration with a correct function:

```
data CList a
  = Nil
  | Sing a
  | Append (CList a) (CList a)
  deriving (Eq)

headAndTail :: CList a -> Maybe (a, CList a)
headAndTail Nil = Nothing
headAndTail (Sing a) = Just (a, Nil)
headAndTail (Append a b) = 
  case headAndTail a of
    Nothing -> headAndTail b
    Just (head, tail) -> Just (head, Append tail b)
```

Comment: Having two types ensures that `Nil` nodes can only appear at the top, so you don't have to worry about large subtrees of only `Append` and `Nil` accumulating in the data structure.

Comment: @hammar Yeah, but then you'll have to burden the outer APIs with managing these two types with a bunch of pattern matching. Also this will result in immideate calculation of results instead of lazily accumulating the operations, which seems to be the whole point of that datastructure in first place.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov on the other hand, appends can be done in constant time. But I'm pretty sure this is a homework assignment and not intended as a practical list implementation.