# Generic version of tail for List type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, fold

It is quite easy to express *head* with *foldr*:

```
head xs = foldr const (error "Empty list") xs
```

Is there a generic way to express *tail* without using constructors?
I already found this answer ([Getting the head and tail of a custom List type Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651772/getting-the-head-and-tail-of-a-custom-list-type-haskell)) which says "no". If this is impossible could someone please explain why?

Comment: I don't understand your constraints. Why is `foldr` allowed, but constructors are not? Is `foldr` the only list function that is allowed?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that by "without using constructors" you mean "without pattern matching on the constructors for the `[]` type".  If this assumption is wrong then this answer might not be what you're looking for.

---

You can do it pretty easily using `Maybe`:

```
import Data.Maybe

tail'
    = fromJust    -- Substitute if you want a different error message for empty lists
    . foldl go Nothing
    where
        go Nothing _ = Just []
        go (Just y) x = Just $ y ++ [x]
```

This isn't the most efficient solution, it's just a proof by construction.

Similarly you can implement `init` with

```
init'
    = fromJust'
    . foldr go Nothing
    where
        go _ Nothing = Just []
        go x (Just y) = Just $ x : y
        fromJust' (Just x) = x
        fromJust' Nothing = error "init': empty list"
```

Answer (score 2):

`foldr` roughly transforms the list into its Church encoding of type

```
forall b . b -> (a -> b -> b) -> b
```

Essentially, strips away all the `:` and `[]` constructors, replacing them with two user-provided values.

If you want the head, then you can do it easily, as you noticed. However, if you want the tail, you have to re-insert the `:` constructor which has been stripped away. For instance, @bheklilr's solution has to use constructors in its `go` part for this reason.